# iOS: Nesting arrays in a second view controller - use objects?

Tags: ios, object, delegates, multidimensional-array

In my app an NSArray is created to store various results from a library search. The idea is that each NSArray of results should also be stored locally so that if the search is made again in the future the local results are retrieved.

Now, I've been thinking about two different approaches. The first is to simply make an array in the second view controller that stores the different results arrays. The second is to instead make a class called Search (for example) that has an NSArray attribute to store the results. This object would be initiated in the second view controller (which would then add it to its own array).

Does this make sense? In terms of memory management is one better than the other? Also, I'll need to use the delegate function to get the data across to the second view controller, right? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't see a big difference. To clarify on the second option, create a singleton object that your Search class makes available to any client class (the view controllers). That singleton provides a store function and a retrieve last result function.

You can make this even simpler by just using the class itself - class methods to store and retrieve, and the class then uses a static NSMutableArray (or NSArray) to keep save the objects.

If you want to make this array available across restarts, then use NSUserDefaults. If things in your array cannot be saved in defaults (some objects cannot) you can possibly turn the array into a NSData object and store that (if all objects comply with NSCoding you are in good shape.